# как обработать нажатие кнопки jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

Я вытаскиваю страницу сайта, нахожу элемент отвечающий за поиск.

Нужно организовать событие "нажатие на кнопку", это возможно? Как это сделать?

```
    Document doc;
    Elements inp = new Elements();
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect("сайт").get();
        inp = doc.select("#id_elementa");
        inp.first().val("устанавливаем значение поиска");

    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Код формы

```
<form id="search_form" class="" 
onsubmit=" if (!this.form_submit_tracked) { this.form_submit_tracked = 1; 
var category_checkbox = document.getElementById('category'); 
var tag_checkbox = document.getElementById('search_in_tag'); 
var ga_action = 'top'; 
if (category_checkbox) { ga_action += '_category'; } 
else if (tag_checkbox) { ga_action += '_tag'; } 
require('Tracking').gatrack_force('search', ga_action, {}); }" 
method="get" action="http://...." name="search_form">
```

Comment: Просто заполнить поля и нажать на кнопку с помощью Jsoup нельзя, тут нужно что-то вроде [Selenium Webdriver](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/). Jsoup может [оправлять POST-запросы](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10012969/5661663), но вам нужно будет самому достать из формы все параметры.

Comment: Для редактирования вопроса используйте кнопку [edit].

Comment: спасибо, буду значить силениум использовать